# cast error on OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android

This is my affected code

```
Object[] rooms = new Object[]{
    new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            tmEditor.putInt("level", position);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    }, 
    new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            tmEditor.putInt("amount", position);
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is when I call it somewhere else with

```
((Spinner) widget).setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) rooms[1]);
```

Then I get a cast exception error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ssttevee.Loki$1$8 cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener
```

Comment: Are you sure not overwriting rooms[1] before use, and that your onitem listener is the android.widget one? Try using the instanceof keyword to check its type prior to cast.

Comment: esentsov caught my mistake, I cast it to OnItemClickListener rather than OnItemSelectedListener -facepalm-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot cast `AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener` to `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`. 
Use `setOnItemSelectedListener` or change `rooms` to array of  `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener`.